# How can I change percent value of jquery easyPiechart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

Recently my html guy implemented `piechart` using `jquery` plug -in name as `easyPieChart` just like in the following way.

[image]

html code:

```
<span class="chart pull-right" data-percent="45" id="_percentUpdate">
    <div class="flip-container">
      <div class="flipper" onclick="this.classList.toggle('flipped')" id="conserHoursFlip">
       <div class="front percent"></div>
       <div class="back percent"></div>
      </div>
    </div>                                              
<span>
```

I want to change dynamically `percent` value through JavaScript or backbone.js,but I can't able to fix this.

can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the percent dynamically with Javascript, use this :

```
$('.chart').data('easyPieChart').update(40);
```

Comment: I am getting error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'update' of undefined `, after running your code.because of that my further logic was not working.can you please tell me why I am getting this this.How can I prevent this.

Comment: Can you add the code you use to initialize the chart ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I found it why I am getting because I used wrong spelling. can you tell How can I change the `barcolor` property value.Why I want in my application color of the bar will change dynamically.

Comment: It updates the chart border but the percentage number is not updating